# Weird collapsed column headers

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

When setting the `Width` of a data grids colum to `*` the columns will appear somehow collapsed like in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

After I add some data to the data grid and somehow force a redraw, the columns suddenly appear as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using `DataGridTemplateColumn`. Below is some sample code:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*"
                        Header="Name">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding FullName, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding FullName, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: You dont need normally that star. It will be automatically adjusted!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue: I added an empty group style and that causes the columns to appear like shown in the screenshot above.